# Redux form with controlled FieldArray

Tags: javascript, node.js, redux, redux-form

So, I'm running into a problem. Suppose I have the following Json file from backend

```
companies: [
  alpha: {
    employees: ['A','B','C']
  },
  beta: {
    employees: ['E','F']
  }
]
```

And I want to create a form that has a dropdown as well as a multi-select checkbox. The multi-select will allow you to choose the company, and the multi-select would then be changed to the employees. I got that part working using formValueSelector

Now, the issue is when I grab the list of employees, the `values` field in `redux-form` looks something like this

```
onSubmit: (values, dispatch, props) => {
  console.log(values)
  // {
  //   A: true,
  //   B: true,
  //   C: true
  // }
}
```

Instead, I want to receive something like this

```
{
  employees: ['A', 'B', 'C']
}
```

I looked at redux-form's `FieldArray` element, and it seems to be just what I needed. However, I can't seem to change the `fields` props passed into the element when I select a different company. I can't quite figure out how to update that programmatically. Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: `console.log({employees: Object.keys(values)});` does this get you closer?

Comment: Yes, though the problem is the form has a lot more fields than just that, values actually have things like {firstName: 'Jon', lastName: 'Doe'...} etc, and I don't want them all in an array

Comment: My current workaround is to have a mapping method that takes all possible employees for the selected company and generate the array from values, which works just fine. I'm just wondering if there's a better, less hacky way to do this so that the result can be represented in an array

Comment: Could you show the code of the list of employees to be selected?